# EF on manjaro shows "Could not execute" but it's installed

Tags: c#, linux, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to work with ef, but it doesn't wanna work

What is the problem?

I've installed ef as global, bash see dotnet, so the path is ok, but it doesn't work

```
[pupptmstr@pupptmstrLapbook ~]$ dotnet --version
3.1.107
[pupptmstr@pupptmstrLapbook ~]$ dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.
[pupptmstr@pupptmstrLapbook ~]$ dotnet ef
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
[pupptmstr@pupptmstrLapbook ~]$ dotnet tool list
Package Id      Version      Commands      Manifest
---------------------------------------------------
[pupptmstr@pupptmstrLapbook ~]$
```

Comment: Did you try relaunching bash?

Comment: Few times. I've been relainching bash and OS

Comment: Ok, I did "which dotnet-ef" and it shows the tool is located in ~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef. Check if it there. If you find it there, then maybe you can simply try to add ~/.dotnet/tools to your PATH.